# Is it possible to develop an add-on for Google Calendar?

Tags: add-on, gmail-addons, google-calendar-recurring-events

We would like to create a google Calendar add-on/plugin/extension that will let us push the event to our cloud hosted application when creating or editing an event in Google calendar.

We have a cloud hosted application that our clients use. One of the features in our application is events. Our clients would like to have this feature wherein they can push any event from their Google Calendar to our application. We have been trying and searching but while its possible to create such add-ons for gmail and google docs, we cannot find anything for calendar. It will help if someone can point us to a way by which we can achieve this. Thanks.